# how use dll files in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, dll, c++builder

I need generate Dll file from matlab cods and use this in C++. I can not couple dll file in c++. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

This looks promising: [How do I create a C - shared library with MATLAB Compiler 3.0 which can be used in other projects?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18CBI/index.html?solution=1-18CBI)

In short:

1. Compile your MATLAB files into a DLL (on Windows): `mcc -t -L C -W lib:mylib -T link:lib -h <MATLAB files> libmmfile.mlib`
2. Add `mylib.lib` to your MSVC (or your own IDE) project
3. Make sure to call the initialization and termination routines from your
   code before calling any of the MATLAB files that are compiled. You need to call: `mylibInitialize();`
   Afterwards, you should call the termination routine: `mylibTerminate();`
   All of the symbols in `mylib.dll` will also appear in `mylib.h`.
4. You can call the functions compiled from the MATLAB code by invoking `mlfFoo(...)`, from your C code.